# nodejs + express , loading -forms- module from external .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express

there is a good advice at : [How to use forms module in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631060/how-to-use-forms-module-in-node-js)

i want to thank authors for the info, but how to deals with forms ( npm forms) if i want to separate it from the main code , i mean how to put forms code in file : form1.js and then require it in mainapp.js

so how to **load and execute the code** from another file (in this case to render Rendering a HTML representation of the form: reg_form.toHTML();

and what is the ideology to keep all that small parts clean ? if i want to assemble many parts.js to mainapp.js ?

thank You for response